# Laravel PostgreSQL Issue on updateOrCreateGroup

Tags: database, laravel, postgresql

when I use updateOrCreate method on MySQL it's working fine on both conditions create or update. but when I use in PostgreSQL it's update is fine but when creates, show this error:

"SQLSTATE[23502]: Not null violation: 7 ERROR: null value in column "group_id" violates not-null constraint DETAIL: Failing row contains (null, aaa, 2020-06-24 17:14:54, 2020-06-24 17:14:54). (SQL: insert into "groups" ("group_id", "title", "updated_at", "created_at") values (?, aaa, 2020-06-24 17:14:54, 2020-06-24 17:14:54) returning "group_id")"

my code:

```
    protected $primaryKey = 'group_id';
    protected $guarded = [''];
    public $incrementing = true;

public function updateOrCreateGroup($data, $id)
    {
        return $this::updateOrCreate(
            ['group_id' => $id],
            $data
        );
    }
```

Comment: what is in the `$data` array?  do you have a `group_id` key in `$data`?

Comment: is `group_id` actually an auto increment field?

Comment: Looks like the $id that you pass is null.

Comment: $no don't have group_id in key in $data. it has other attributes of table just like the title.

Comment: yes, on create case $id is null but on update case it not be.so my update case is wokring fine but no create case.